# JSON/JavaScript Function Issue

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've been working on a function for a web page that should display information from a JSON object depending upon two attributes, the attendance day and start time. The JSON and function are as follows is as follows:

```js
var courses = [{
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "8:00",
  "End_Time": "9:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "10:30",
  "End_Time": "11:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "12:30",
  "End_Time": "1:30",
  "Attendance": "Wednesday"
}];

function plotCourse() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == "Monday" && course.Start_Time == "10:30") {
      alert(course.Attendance);
      alert(course.Start_Time);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using alert() for testing purposes. However, I don't seem to get a returned value, and I'm a bit stumped and what may be going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call plotCourse()

Comment: this is just a hunch, and I may be wrong, but in your example you don't actually call the `plotCourse()` function. You just define it.

Answer (score 2):

you forget to call it: `plotCourse();`, or use **IIFE** instead. please check this one

```js
var courses = [{
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "8:00",
  "End_Time": "9:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "10:30",
  "End_Time": "11:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "12:30",
  "End_Time": "1:30",
  "Attendance": "Wednesday"
}];

(function() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == "Monday" && course.Start_Time == "10:30") {
      alert(course.Attendance);
      alert(course.Start_Time);
    }
  }
})(); /* IIFE*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you were calling the function.

Working here:

```js
var courses = [{
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "8:00",
  "End_Time": "9:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "10:30",
  "End_Time": "11:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "12:30",
  "End_Time": "1:30",
  "Attendance": "Wednesday"
}];

function plotCourse() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == "Monday" && course.Start_Time == "10:30") {
      console.log(course.Attendance);
      console.log(course.Start_Time);
    }
  }
}
plotCourse(); //Involed the function
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the `plotCourse()` function.

```js
var courses = [{
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "8:00",
  "End_Time": "9:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "10:30",
  "End_Time": "11:30",
  "Attendance": "Monday"
}, {
  "dept": "CSC",
  "id": "3380",
  "instructor": "Douglas",
  "Location": "012 Lockett",
  "Start_Time": "12:30",
  "End_Time": "1:30",
  "Attendance": "Wednesday"
}];

function plotCourse() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == "Monday" && course.Start_Time == "10:30") {
      alert(course.Attendance);
      alert(course.Start_Time);
    }
  }
}

plotCourse();
```

Answer (score 0):

the example you proposed was not the called function.
iniltre I made a small correction to the **FOR** loop.. =)

```
function plotCourse() {
  for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++) { // Control if the element exists
    var course = courses[i];
    console.log(course);
    if (course.Attendance == "Monday" && course.Start_Time == "10:30") {
      alert(course.Attendance);
      alert(course.Start_Time);
    }
  }
}

plotCourse(); // launch the function!
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, you need to call the function. It's working for me when I call it.